# How to extract numpy arrays from Theano tensor?

Tags: python, theano, conv-neural-network, lasagne, tensor

We are working on an implementation of 3D Convolutional Neural Networks for segmentation of 3D medical images.

We have built a network with Lasagne and Theano, which successfully builds a 5D tensor. We want to extract actual 'images' as 3D numpy arrays from this tensor to see what the segmented maps actually look like.

We get the output like this:

```
prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(layer)
```

Then define loss, updates, etc.

And define the theano function like this:

```
train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], loss, updates=updates)
```

We then train a network in a for loop:

```
for epoch in range(10):
  loss = train_fn(train_data, train_seg)
  print("Epoch %d: Loss %g" % (epoch + 1, loss))
```

We have tried using the eval function like this:

```
print(eval('prediction[2]'))
```

which outputs:

```
Subtensor{int64}.0
```

But what we actually want to get are the actual outputs of the network (based on our inputs, they should be of size 24*160*160), so the output that the loss function takes to compare it with our test data.
Can anyone help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prediction  is just a theano tensor. what you have to do is call it through theano function like how you did with the loss variable.

ex.

```
prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(theano tensor)  
f = theano.function([Theano tensor],prediction)
X must be your data 
maps = f(X)
```